# How to add a scrollbar to an overlapping canvas in Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make an application for a school project, one of the features is a messaging service where users can message each other, this is accessed via a button in which the messaging GUI is loaded. I have already added a canvas as the background for the main GUI at the start of the program but for the message interface I have added another canvas which overlaps and will be using a scrollbar to scroll through the messages and display them.

In essence my problem is that I would like to position another canvas on top of the main canvas using co-ordinates and add a scrollbar which only fits to the right hand side of this smaller canvas.

Thanks in advance :)

I have tried to add a scrollbar to it using pack(), grid(), place() and canvas.create_window() however in all instances the scrollbar either does not appear, does not fill the entire right hand side of the second canvas, or is not placed in the correct position. The closest I got was with the place() function where I have managed to position the scrollbar and canvas using "relx", "rely" and "relheight" however the scrollbar is not scrolling the canvas.

```
   root = Tk() #creates the GUI
   root.title("Eclass") 
   root.iconbitmap(default='icon.ico') #sets icon
   root.state('zoomed') 
   backgroundcolour = root.cget("bg") 
   screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth() - 15
   screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

   canvas = Canvas(root, width = screen_width, height = screen_height)

   def messaging():
       canvas.delete("all")

       msg_canvas = Canvas(canvas, width = 1530, height = 730, bg = "red")
       #canvas.create_window(1123,600, window = msg_canvas) this is where I tried to add the second canvas using the create_Window function      

       msg_canvas.place(relx=0.186, rely=0.227)

       msg_scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas, orient="vertical",command=msg_canvas.yview)
       msg_scrollbar.place(relx=0.975,rely=0.2295, relheight = 0.717)

       msg_canvas.config(scrollregion=msg_canvas.bbox(ALL))
```

I expect the canvas to be placed within the current co-ordinates given via relx and rely or in previous trial the co-ordinates in canvas.create_window(), I then expect the msg_scrollbar to be on the right hand side of msg_canvas and fill to its Y (the height of the scrollbar should be the same as the height of the canvas). In actuality the canvas and scrollbar are in the correct co-ordinates however the scrollbar does not scroll the msg_canvas even after moving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> , In essence, my problem is that I would like to position another canvas on top of the main canvas using co-ordinates and add a scrollbar which only fits the right-hand side of this smaller canvas.

I recommend *against* using `place`. Both `pack` and `grid` are better for creating code that is responsive to changes in resolution, window size, and fonts.

IMHO, the simplest solution is to use `pack` to put the main canvas at the bottom, then in the remaining space put the scrollbar on the right and the secondary canvas on the left. Note: the order is important, as each time you call `pack` it will use up all of the space on the given side, reducing the space available to future widgets.

```
canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
msg_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
msg_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

You can accomplish the same thing with `grid`, but it requires additional lines of code to configure row and column weights. With `grid` order isn't as important since you are explicitly setting rows and columns.

```
msg_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
msg_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

root.grid_rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```